# 2S BMS shuts down by itself

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, boost, bms

I made a small 2 DC motor Arduino robot car which is powered by two **18650** cells. I am using a **2S BMS** with a **[TP5100](https://voltiq.ru/datasheets/TP5100-datashhet.pdf)** to charge and protect my cells. I am using a **DC-DC boost converter** to make 9 V to drive my **[L298 Motor Driver](https://hallroad.org/l298n-motor-driver-module-in-pakistan.html)**.

The problem I am facing is that the BMS shuts itself down as soon as the motors draw current. The cells' state of charge is not too low. The total voltage of both cells is about 7.2 V. When this happens I apply a small voltage to P+ and P- on the BMS and it starts again and repeats the cycle.

I have tried searching about this problem but couldn't find anything. I am a beginner, so if my question is stupid then excuse me for that.

[image]

Comment: What is the current drawn by the motor/motor driver? I think the (inrush) current is to high for the BMS.

Comment: it's 5V DC with load current not peaking more then 100mah. i've 2 of these, and arduino nano and L298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job of the BMS is to protect the cells. At start-up, the motor draws too much current for the cells. Therefore, the BMS shuts down the battery to protect the cells from that high current.

The problem is not the BMS. The problem is that you neglected to include an essential component in your vehicle: a motor controller.

A motor controller reduces the voltage from the battery voltage to the voltage required by the motor at a given time. It also limits the current. Therefore, at start, the battery current will be low, and the BMS will not trip to protect the cells.

Add a motor controller between the BMS and the motor, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: by motor controller you mean l298 ?
 i have that in it.

Comment: l298 is a bridge driver IC, not a motor controller module. Please link  to the actual part that you have, so I may see whether it's an IC or something else.

Comment: i am using this.
https://hallroad.org/l298n-motor-driver-module-in-pakistan.html

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, that is just an H-bridge, just like you said. It's not an actual motor driver. It;s not better than a set of switches. You need an actual motor driver. An actual motor driver limits the current and controls the speed. Look for an "ESC" (Electronic Speed Control). A cheaper solution is to place an ICL (Inrush Current Limiter) in series with the motor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. that is it I guess. I just recharged my batteries and it isn't stopping now. guess there's enough current now.